# Hide/Show columns dynamically of lightning-datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, js

Is there a way to hide/show columns of lightning-datatable dynamically? Not just headers, but the whole columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is removing the desired element from the columns array, or use the original set if you want it back.

```
<template>
    <lightning-input type="toggle" 
        label="Show/Hide Column" 
        checked={visible}
        message-toggle-active="Column visible"
        message-toggle-inactive="Column hidden"
        onchange={handleCheckboxChange}></lightning-input>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>    
</template>
```

then on the controller:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import fetchDataHelper from './fetchDataHelper';
const cols = [
        { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' },
        { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url' },
        { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
        { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
        { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
    ];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    visible = true;
    data = [];
    columns = cols;
    // event to handle column display, in this example, it is just a toggle button
    handleCheckboxChange(e) {
        this.visible = !this.visible;
        if (this.visible) {
            this.columns = [...cols];
        } else {
            // return every column but the one you want to hide
            this.columns = [...cols].filter(col => col.fieldName != 'name');
        }
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-await
    async connectedCallback() {
        const data = await fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords: 100 });
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much!